# How to read this XML in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my XML

```
<<Scoops Location="Mumbai">
```

```
<scoop name="![CDATA[International Physical Theatre Laboratory...Open to Actors from Different Countries...]]" link="/dramas/scoops/10-jan-13-international-physical-theatre-laboratory/967.htm" dateadded="1/13/2010 12:00:00 AM" />
<scoop name="![CDATA[IIT Bombay's ANNUAL THEATREFEST 2010...]]" link="/dramas/scoops/10-jan-07-iit-bombays-annual-theatrefeast-2010/966.htm" dateadded="1/7/2010 12:00:00 AM" />
<scoop name="![CDATA[Natak Company from Pune to Stage Three of their Award Winning Marathi Plays...]]" link="/dramas/scoops/10-jan-06-natak-company-from-pune-stage-three-their-marathi-play/964.htm" dateadded="1/6/2010 12:00:00 AM" />
<scoop name="![CDATA[Premiere Show of Ideas Unlimited's AMAR FAL...]]" link="/dramas/scoops/10-jan-06-premiere-shows-of-ideas-unlimiteds-amar-fal/963.htm" dateadded="1/6/2010 12:00:00 AM" />
```

----------------

I have a DropDownList called `Month`.. And on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, I want to read this XML in month-wise, so for that I have written this code...

```
protected void ddlmonth_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("/Scoops/Archives/2010-Mumbai.xml"));
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(reader);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Scoops/" + ddlmonth.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());

}
```

But I am do not understand how to continue.. So please help me....

Comment: After reading it, what do you want to do with it? Save it to database? Show it to user? Populating another drop-down? what?

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName` expects only a tagname. You're giving it more than that. Either give it "January" to get the January node, or give it "scoop" to select all scoop-nodes. Note: XML is case-sensitive, and "Scoops" is not in your example.

Comment: I want to show that scoop onselected index change of dropdown, I want to read XML directly from that XML file

Comment: @Aties - Please post correct XML markup along with root element and namespace if it is there. Did you store name of fullname of month  or abbr?

Comment: Yes I v=have Fullname of Month, Here I m posting some details XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
protected void ddlmonth_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("/Scoops/Archives/2010-Mumbai.xml"));
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(reader);

    // no need to call Trim(), ASP.NET did that already
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName(ddlmonth.SelectedItem.Text);

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList[0].SelectNodes("scoop"))
    {
        someDropDownList.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value);
    }


}
```

Comment: Actually I am not understanding that what should I write in Foreach loop, Plese u suggest me..  I want to read that data which present in sccop naem tag in XML

Comment: @Aties: I updated my answer. It's actually quite trivial. Just let the IntelliSense help you here. Click the dot "." and you see a dropdownlist in VS what you can use. I assumed you wanted the name-attribute. You can do the same for the datevalue.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ddlmonth.Items.Add(xmldoc.Attributes["name"].Value);

Comment: @Aties: I didn't write `ddlmonth.Items.Add(xmldoc.Attributes["name"].Value);`. I can only assume that you made a typo with `xmldoc`, which should be the variable holding the current node. Other reasons include that your XML example is not equal to what you're actually using.